# Having chosen the correct package (I believe), I cannot still install it. How to fix it?

Tags: openwrt

Thanks to the command "cpuinfo", I've noticed that the "System type" is MediaTek MT7620, "cpu model" is MIPS 24KEc V5.0, so that I downloaded this package

> bash_4.3.39-1_ramips_24kec.ipk

from [Index of /chaos_calmer/15.05/ramips/mt7620/packages/packages/](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ramips/mt7620/packages/packages/)

So I believe that I have got the correct package for my machine, but I can't install it, I use `opkg install /path/to/bash_4.3.39-1_ramips_24kec.ipk`, sure the path is right, and I got

> Unknown package 'bash'.
>
> Collected errors:
>
> - pkg_hash_fetch_best_installation_candidate: Packages for bash found, but incompatible with the architectures configured
> - opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package bash.

From the report, I don't think I need to install something else first (Am I wrong?), and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

UPDATE: The machine runs Pandorabox R2 14.09, with Luci Trunk (0.12+svn-r1024), I have also tried using bash_4.2-5_ramips_24kec.ipk from [Index of /barrier_breaker/14.07/ramips/mt7620a/packages/packages/](https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ramips/mt7620a/packages/packages/)
and [Index of /barrier_breaker/14.07/ramips/mt7620n/packages/packages/](https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ramips/mt7620n/packages/packages/)
I got the same report.

If I am not wrong, the version of firmware of OpenWrt should be 14.07, that's the base of Pandorabox R2 14.09.

Answer (score 0):

I also have OpenWrt, I haven't installed any packages from command line but I use the graphical interface. 
Once connected to your router web page, under `System > Software > Configuration` repositories are listed. Read from that page the url of your repositories.
If you have internet access it suffices to click on the submit button and then choose the right bash package on the list of available pagkages. If otherwise you haven't any internet connection (as I have read on another your question) you can download the package from the the right repository link.

Anyway, I suppose to have your same hardware, based on your `cpuinfo` output. And since you have Pandorabox firmware, I think that the right repository is: http://downloads.openwrt.org.cn/PandoraBox/ralink/packages/packages.